# How can I use express-rate-limit in sailsJS?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, middleware

I want to use a express-rate-limit middleware in sailsJS framework for preventing brute force attacks/ adding attempts for logging in. The documentation shows the implementation for basic nodejs but how can we add that logic in sailsjs framework. I referred to the following doc:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit

Comment: What have you tried? How about [this](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/middleware#?express-middleware-in-sails)?